# not able to install php-devel in aws centos ec2 instance for php version 5.6.22

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I was trying to install php-devel using the command 'sudo yum install php-devel. I am getting error like this

```
--> Processing Conflict: php56-cli-5.6.22-1.125.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-cli < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Processing Conflict: php56-common-5.6.22-1.125.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.22-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have installed the php-devel using the following command

```
sudo yum install php56-devel
```